# Calculating volume of ellipsoid in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: integration, conic-sections, volume, cylindrical-coordinates

I'm trying to calculate the volume of an ellipsoid in cylindrical coordinates but it somehow doesn't turn out right.

The equation of my ellipsoid in cartesian coordinates is :
$$ \left(\frac{x}{b}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{z-c}{c}\right)^2=1
$$
which will be written as:
$$ \left(\frac{r\cos(\theta)}{b}\right)^2+\left(\frac{r\sin(\theta)}{a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{z-c}{c}\right)^2=1
$$
in cylindrical coordinates.
The following integral should give the volume of the ellipsoid:
$$ \int^{2\pi}_{0}{d\theta}\int^{2c}_{0}{dz}\int^{r_{max(z,\theta)}}_{0}{rdr}
$$
Where $r_{max(z,\theta)}$ is the biggest r for every fixed $z$ and $\theta$ which is:
$$ \dfrac{ab\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{z-c}{c}\right)^2}}{\sqrt{a^2\cos^2{\theta}+b^2\sin^2{\theta}}}
$$
Integrating this I get to the following integral which can't be solved in these limits:
$$ \int^{2\pi}_{0}\frac{1}{a^2\cos^2{\theta}+b^2\sin^2{\theta}}{d\theta}
$$
Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong or send me the correct solution? I would really appreciate that!
Please consider that I want to calculate the volume in cylindrical coordinates not spherical or cartesian.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It is not difficult to compute the integral $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{a^2\cos^2\theta+b^2\sin^2\theta}$$ by exploiting symmetry and the substitution $\theta=\arctan u$ over the interval $(0,\pi/2)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Please Take a look at this link : [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F(a%5E2cos%5E2x%2Bb%5E2sin%5E2(x))+from+0+to+2pi)

Comment: @NickySadighi: do not trust machines too much for this kind of task: they have no clue about where $a$ and $b$ lie, and that can be a singular integral for complex values of $a$ and $b$. But we know that $a$ and $b$ are lenghts, and by following my previous hint to the letter we get $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{a^2\cos^2\theta+b^2\sin^2\theta} = \frac{2\pi}{ab}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Let use modified cylindrical coordinates

- $x=br\cos \theta$
- $y=ar\sin \theta$
- $z=cz+c$

and $dx\,dy\,dz=abc \,r \,dr\, d\theta\, dz$

The ellipsoid equation becomes $r^2+z^2=1$ and the integral set up is

$$\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int_{-1}^{1} dz \int_0^{\sqrt{1-z^2}} abc \,r\,dr$$

Comment: @gimusi Sorry but I can't understand how this would solve the problem. Could you explain more please?

Comment: @NickySadighi Now it should be ok! Verify and let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much I was able to solve the question with this hint.

Comment: @NickySadighi I'm very happy for that, well done! Look also to the hint by Jack in the comments! Bye